# Typescript react fetching undefined objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've got some issues feeding my components with sample data. I have created a web api method that returns some json objects:

[
{"id":1,"title":"Master framework","description":"A framework to develope advance UI interfaces for modern web applications","status":"in-progress","color":"#3A7E26"},
{"id":2,"title":"Setup main app solution","description":"An app ","status":"todo","color":"#3A7E26"},
{"id":3,"title":"UI mock creation","description":"Have to be neat a simple","status":"todo","color":"#BD8D31"},
{"id":4,"title":"WebAPI implementation","description":"Based on REST architecture","status":"todo","color":"#BD8D31"}
]

My components:
Dashboard:

```
interface IDashboardState {
    Cards: Card[];
}

export class Dashboard extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, IDashboardState> {
    constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = { Cards: [] };
    }

    public componentDidMount() {

        const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:51429/Home/Cards';
        var cardEntities: CardEntity[];

        fetch(baseUrl)
            .then((response) => (response.json())
                .then((responseData) => {
                    console.log(responseData.length);
                    this.setState({ Cards: responseData })
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log("Error loading data", error);
                }));

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <List Id='todo' Title="To do" Cards={
                    this.state.Cards.filter((card) => card.props.Status === "todo")}
                     />
                <List Id='in-progress' Title="In progress" Cards={
                    this.state.Cards.filter((card) => card.props.Status === "in-progress")}
                     />
                <List Id='done' Title="Done" Cards={
                    this.state.Cards.filter((card) => card.props.Status === "done")}
                     />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

List:

```
interface IListProps {
    Id: string;
    Title: string;
    Cards: Card[];
}
export class List extends React.Component<IListProps, {}> {
    render() {
        var cards = this.props.Cards.map((card => {
            return <Card key={card.props.Id}
                Id={card.props.Id}
                Title={card.props.Title}
                Description={card.props.Description}
                Status={card.props.Status}
                Color={card.props.Color}
                />
        }))

        return (
            <div className="list">
                <h1>{this.props.Title}</h1>
                {cards}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Card:

```
interface ICardProps {
    Id: number;
    Title: string;
    Description: string;
    Status: string;
    Color: string;
}

interface ICardState {
    showDetails: boolean;
}


export class Card extends React.Component<ICardProps, ICardState> {
    constructor(props: ICardProps) {
        super(props)
            this.state = {
        showDetails: false
    };
}

toggleDetails() {
    this.setState({showDetails: ! this.state.showDetails})
}

render() {

    let cardDetails;
    if (this.state.showDetails) {
        cardDetails = (
            <div className="card_details">
                <CheckList CardId={this.props.Id}

                />
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className="card">
            <div>
                <div className="card_title" onClick={this.toggleDetails.bind(this)}>
                    {this.props.Title}
                </div>
                <div className="card_description">
                    {this.props.Description}
                </div>
                {cardDetails}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I thought react while fetching would automatically assign my json to Card object, but it leaves them as undefined and no content is rendered. Any ideas why?

Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: Update your `filter` calls to `filter(card => card.status === "todo")` and the mapping within `List` render to be `Title={card.title}`

Answer (score 1):

The response data are not mapped correctly to props.

#### Dashboard

```
interface CardData {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  status: string;
  color: string;
}

interface IDashboardState {
  cards: CardData[];
}

export class Dashboard extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, IDashboardState> {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { cards: [] };
  }

  public componentDidMount() {

    const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:51429/Home/Cards';
    var cardEntities: CardEntity[];

    fetch(baseUrl)
      .then((response) => (response.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
          console.log(responseData.length);
          this.setState({ cards: responseData as CardData[] })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log("Error loading data", error);
        }));

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <List Id='todo' Title="To do" Cards={
          this.state.cards.filter((card) => card.status === "todo")}
        />
        <List Id='in-progress' Title="In progress" Cards={
          this.state.cards.filter((card) => card.status === "in-progress")}
        />
        <List Id='done' Title="Done" Cards={
          this.state.cards.filter((card) => card.status === "done")}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

#### List

```
interface IListProps {
  Id: string;
  Title: string;
  Cards: Card[];
}

export class List extends React.Component<IListProps, {}> {
  render() {
    var cards = this.props.Cards.map(card => {
      return
        <Card key={card.id}
          Id={card.id}
          Title={card.title}
          Description={card.description}
          Status={card.status}
          Color={card.color}
        />
    })

    return (
      <div className="list">
        <h1>{this.props.Title}</h1>
        {cards}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In Dashboard render() function, I cant change from
card.props.status to card.status, as the child component take in props a Card object (which already is a react component class extension)

Comment: Your `Dashboard` state property `Cards` should have the shape of an array containing objects shaped like the JSON response. Call it `CardData` so you don't mix it up with `Card` component. Hope this is clear.

Comment: still doesnt render card components